# Best way of creating a scene representation with seats number using html and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to represent a scene plan where users will be able to select a couple of seats and will be able to buy it by clicking on it.

I would use a simple HTML image map, but my little finger says it's not the most efficient way.

So, only using css and html (or Jquery, or even a plugin), how can I do this?

When the mouse pass over the seat, a kind of tooltip would actually give the seat number and the color of the seat itself could change.

Is an image map a good idea?

Comment: Image map would be a good idea if there weren't 200 other images to display on hover ([example with 30 french Régions and overseas](http://www.orientation-pour-tous.fr/spip.php?page=offres)). Too bad it doesn't scale because it's accessible as long as area[alt] are OK (same as img[alt])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image map its not a good idea.

The right way is using HTML and CSS to create all the seats, and using jQuery event on click to do the buy seat stuff.

For the tooltip there is a bunch of plugins on google just make a simple search, my favorite is  [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)

Comment: You mean, placing seats using css over a plan? or drawing it with css?

Comment: Place seats using HTML/CSS and capture click events with jQuery. Something like: <div class="seat" rel="seat-1">...</div> and then, in jQuery: $("div.seat").click(function() { ... });

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue and I'm going with SVG.
Take a look at raphael.js (http://raphaeljs.com/) and tools like that.